# How to get IP addresses of applications that have consumed most CPU in last 10 minutes in Db2/Linux?

Tags: db2, monitoring, db2-luw, cpu

Db2 v11.1 on Linux I would like to get top 5 SQL statements that consumed the most CPU in last 10 minutes and there corresponding IP addresses.

I queried "package cache" table function and I get SQL statements. This is fine.

```
SELECT
    A.STMT_TEXT
FROM
    TABLE(MON_GET_PKG_CACHE_STMT (NULL, NULL, NULL, -2)) AS A
WHERE
    A.LAST_METRICS_UPDATE > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 10 MINUTES
ORDER BY TOTAL_CPU_TIME DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Now I would like to get IP addresses for Db2 clients that executed those SQLs.

I tried to join above "package cache" data with "connections" where IP address is stored:

```
SELECT
    B.APPLICATION_ID,
    A.STMT_TEXT
FROM
    TABLE(MON_GET_PKG_CACHE_STMT (NULL, NULL, NULL, -2)) AS A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE(MON_GET_CONNECTION(CAST(NULL AS BIGINT), -2)) AS B
       ON A.EXECUTABLE_ID = B.LAST_EXECUTABLE_ID
WHERE
    A.LAST_METRICS_UPDATE > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 10 MINUTES
ORDER BY TOTAL_CPU_TIME DESC
LIMIT 5
```

In majority of cases null is returned for APPLICATION_ID field. This makes sense, because "connection" table function holds info about currently connected applications, but when I executed above select statement every 10 minutes, majority of applications have already disconnected from database and so connection info is lost.

**Question:** How to get IP address for SQLs that have consumed the most CPU in last 10 minutes?

Comment: One might use an activity event monitor -- documentation describes in detail how to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

Like mustaccio says you probably should have a look at event monitors. That said, an alternative is to take a snapshot into a temp table, wait a while and then compare a new snapshot with the temp table. Below is an example for a sh script that you can adapt to your needs:

```
#!/bin/sh

OPTS=`getopt d:t: "$@"`
eval set -- "$OPTS"

tm=10
while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        -d) db="$2"; shift 2;;
        -t) tm="$2"; shift 2;;
        --) shift; break;;
    esac
done

db2 connect to $db
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Unable to connect to $db"
    exit 1
fi

db2 +c "create view stmt_metrics
  (executable_id, num_executions, rows_read, rows_modified, stmt_text)
as select executable_id, num_executions, rows_read, rows_modified, stmt_text
   from TABLE (MON_GET_PKG_CACHE_STMT('d', null, null, -1))"

db2 +c "create global temporary table stmt_samples as (
    select * from stmt_metrics) 
definition only on commit delete rows"

db2 +c "create view stmts_delta (executable_id, num_executions, rows_read, rows_modified, stmt_text)
as
select t2.executable_id
     , t2.num_executions - t1.num_executions as num_executions
     , t2.rows_read - t1.rows_read as rows_read
     , t2.rows_modified - t1.rows_modified as rows_modified
     , t2.stmt_text
from stmt_metrics as t2
   , stmt_samples as t1
where t2.executable_id = t1.executable_id"

db2 +c "insert into stmt_samples select * from stmt_metrics"

sleep $tm

db2 -x +c "select * from stmts_delta order by rows_modified desc fetch first 10 rows only"


db2 rollback
```

Here is an example of an activity event monitor:

```
db2 connect to <db>
db2 "alter service class sysdefaultsubclass under
     sysdefaultuserclass collect activity data on all database
     partitions with details and values"

db2 "create event monitor act_stmt for activities write to table manualstart"

db2 "set event monitor act_stmt state = 1"
```

You will get a number of tables created, I believe you will be mostly interested in ACTIVITYMETRICS_ACT_STMT.

You can run your workload and then query that table (an example, there are a lot of other metrics that you might be interested in):

```
db2 "select APPL_ID, sum(TOTAL_CPU_TIME) as SUM_TOTAL_CPU_TIME
     from ACTIVITYMETRICS_ACT_STMT 
     where EVENT_TIMESTAMP > current_timestamp - 10 minutes      
     group by APPL_ID"

APPL_ID                            SUM_TOTAL_CPU_TIME  
*LOCAL.db2inst1.220316094506                       2027
*LOCAL.db2inst1.220316094705                        162
13x.23x.82.116.58680.220316094933                    27
13x.23x.82.116.58788.220316095429                    22
13x.23x.82.116.58790.220316095430                 17367
13x.23x.82.116.58794.220316095447                   429

6 record(s) selected.
```

I replaced two digits with x. If you want to isolate the IP:

```
db2 "select REGEXP_SUBSTR(APPL_ID, '^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', 1, 1), sum(TOTAL_CPU_TIME) as SUM_TOTAL_CPU_TIME 
     from ACTIVITYMETRICS_ACT_STMT 
     where EVENT_TIMESTAMP > current_timestamp - 10 minutes      
     group by REGEXP_SUBSTR(APPL_ID, '^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', 1, 1)"

1                             SUM_TOTAL_CPU_TIME  
13x.23x.82.116                                  17845
-                                               22640
```

Remember to stop the monitor when you are finished

Comment: Thanks for idea, to solve the problem using shell scripting. There is still open problem of how to get IP address (the main problem of this thread). Like I see it, I could run MON_GET_CONNECTION more frequently to get info and then join the data retrieved by MON_GET_PKG_CACHE_STMT.

Comment: The package cache is in a sense unaware of who uses the compiled package, it aggregates metrics such as rows read, CPU usage, etc regardless of who uses it. I'll have a look and see if I can come up with something, but for a per connection based usage, you will probably be better of with a monitor.

Comment: @folow, I added an example of a monitor to my answer

Comment: @folow, I managed to leave out the monitor it self, added it now, sorry

Answer (score 1):

The only way to "bind" statements executed with their text and cpu consumed to applications is event monitor for activities.
But collection of such [information](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=monitors-information-written-tables-activities-event-monitor) for all applications in the database may be very expensive - there is a huge amount of data collected to the event monitor tables by default.
The suggestion is to limit the amount of data collected as much as possible with the following technique (example for non-partitioned database env), which significantly limits the data collected with exact set of columns specified for each logical data group.

```
CREATE TABLE ACTIVITYSTMT_ACT_LIM  
(
    ACTIVITY_ID BIGINT NOT NULL , 
    APPL_ID VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL , 
    UOW_ID INTEGER NOT NULL ,  
    STMT_TEXT CLOB(2M) INLINE LENGTH 2681 NOT LOGGED COMPACT 
)   
IN SYSTOOLSPACE;

CREATE TABLE ACTIVITY_ACT_LIM  
(
    ACTIVITY_ID BIGINT NOT NULL , 
    APPL_ID VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL , 
    UOW_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ADDRESS VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL ,
    TIME_COMPLETED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL , 
    TIME_STARTED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL   
)   
IN SYSTOOLSPACE;

CREATE TABLE ACTIVITYMETRICS_ACT_LIM
(
    ACTIVITY_ID BIGINT NOT NULL ,
    APPL_ID VARCHAR(64 OCTETS) NOT NULL ,
    UOW_ID INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    TOTAL_CPU_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL
)   
IN SYSTOOLSPACE;

CREATE EVENT MONITOR ACT_LIM
       FOR ACTIVITIES
       WRITE TO TABLE
         ACTIVITY        (TABLE ACTIVITY_ACT_LIM ),
         ACTIVITYSTMT    (TABLE ACTIVITYSTMT_ACT_LIM ),
         ACTIVITYMETRICS (TABLE ACTIVITYMETRICS_ACT_LIM )
MANUALSTART;

-- activate activity data collection at the default user workload level
ALTER WORKLOAD SYSDEFAULTUSERWORKLOAD COLLECT ACTIVITY DATA ON COORDINATOR WITH DETAILS;

-- switch the event monitor on
SET EVENT MONITOR ACT_LIM STATE 1;
-- wait some time

-- switch the event monitor off
SET EVENT MONITOR ACT_LIM STATE 0;
-- deactivate activity data collection at the default user workload level
ALTER WORKLOAD SYSDEFAULTUSERWORKLOAD COLLECT ACTIVITY DATA NONE;

-- Analysis
SELECT 
  A.ADDRESS
, M.TOTAL_CPU_TIME
, A.APPL_ID, A.UOW_ID, A.ACTIVITY_ID
, VARCHAR(S.STMT_TEXT, 256) stmt_text
FROM ACTIVITY_ACT_LIM A
JOIN ACTIVITYSTMT_ACT_LIM S 
    ON (S.APPL_ID, S.UOW_ID, S.ACTIVITY_ID) = (A.APPL_ID, A.UOW_ID, A.ACTIVITY_ID) 
JOIN ACTIVITYMETRICS_ACT_LIM M
    ON (M.APPL_ID, M.UOW_ID, M.ACTIVITY_ID) = (A.APPL_ID, A.UOW_ID, A.ACTIVITY_ID)
--WHERE A.TIME_STARTED BETWEEN ... AND ...
--ORDER BY A.TIME_STARTED DESC
;
```